# Combination of Citrix Receiver and RDP results in mouse lags

Tags: remote-desktop, mouse, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012, citrix-receiver

I'm logging in to a remote machine running Windows Server 2003 Enterprise via Citrix Receiver (via my web browser and Java). So far, everything works fine.
However, when I use RDP on the Citrix machine to log into a Windows Server 2012 machine (which is only accessible through the first one), I get massive lags for my mouse.
The mouse pointer will jump in steps of a few centimers when I move it, which makes working with a GUI-based tool very difficult.

I've tried changing the RDP connection settings to low resolution and slow connection (as far down as Modem speed), but to no avail. The remote Win2012 server is using the basic theme. Is there anything else I can try?

Note: When I log into the Citrix machine locally (via a thin client in the office), there are only slight, acceptable lags on the RDP connection. Only when I log into that Citrix machine from outside the intranet do the lags appear. I cannot ping the Server running the Citrix application, but I'm never more than a few hundred km away from it.

Comment: Are you seeing lags when operating the server over Citrix as well (not jump to the RDP box)? Did you launch Task Manager to investigate if something is eating up a lot of CPU / memory / disk IO?

Comment: On Citrix everything is completely smooth, CPU load is below 10% on both machines, memory less than 1/3 used, no significant i/o. I'm really at a loss, I can only assume that latency somehow multiplies.

Comment: ok. But you say that the mouse will "jump" - usually, the local system (the computer from which you are logging into the Citrix box) handles the movement and performance of that. Can you check CPU / memory on the local machine?

Comment: And also, does this happen always or just sometimes (i.e.: when the link is congested between you and the Citrix box)?

Comment: It's all the time, and from all locations (with different ISPs) I've tested. The local machine is pretty powerful and low on resource usage. My impression is that the mouse movement for the Citrix machine is indeed handled on my local one and is therefore smooth .The mouse movement for the RDP one appears to be handled by the Citrix machine, though, and those two don't seem to play together very well. Unfortunately the RDP one isn't accesible directly from the outside for security reasons, so I can't circumvent Citrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a Windows 2012 issue and is easy to fix. All you need to do is disable Mouse Shadows on the RDP target.

Comment: I'm not working for that specific client at the moment, so I can't test it, but I will make sure to do so should the problem arise again.

Comment: Update: a colleague testet it and this does the trick! Thanks a lot for your suggestion.